# binding groupboxes to may stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, groupbox

I want to bind Groupboxes to my stackpanel.

c#:

```
internal ObservableCollection<GroupBox> BindingTest
{
    get
    {
        ObservableCollection<GroupBox> collection = new ObservableCollection<GroupBox>();
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
        {
            GroupBox groupBox = new GroupBox();
            groupBox.Header = " ... Header ... ";
            groupBox.Content = " ... Content ... ";
            collection.Add(groupBox);
        }

            return collection;
    }
}
```

and the xaml code:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Dynamic" Grid.Row="1" Margin="29,118,6,0">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BindingTest}" Height="482">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <GroupBox>
                    <GroupBox.Header>{Binding Path=Header}</GroupBox.Header>
                    <GroupBox.Content>{Binding Path=Content}</GroupBox.Content>
                </GroupBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

where does my error in reasoning?

Comment: Firstly, the StackPanel is not needed; you only need the ItemsControl.  Secondly, is you DataContext set to `this`?

Comment: @benjer3 1: ok ;) 2: it set to my view model where BindingTest ist located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF Binding, you usually don't bind to Controls, you just bind to objects and let the Markup handle UI details. Ideally your objects should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the Binding of property changes. Control creation is handled already by the `DataTemplate`, it already creates a `GroupBox` for you and binds its properties to the properties of the object used in the binding.

Your `ViewModel` should, if possible, **not** know anything about the UI, or use any Controls. The MVVM pattern is meant to decouple UI and Data/Logic.

The class of your data objects could look something like this:

```
public class DataObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string header;
    private string content;

    public string Header {
        get { return header; }
        set { header = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Header"); }
    }

    public string Content {
        get { return content; }
        set { content= value; RaisePropertyChanged("Content"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) { 
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); 
        }
    }
}
```

The property you bind to would also look different:

```
internal ObservableCollection<DataObject> BindingTest
{
    get
    {
        ObservableCollection<DataObject> collection = new ObservableCollection<DataObject>();
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
        {
            DataObject item = new DataObject ();
            item.Header = " ... Header ... ";
            item.Content = " ... Content ... ";
            collection.Add(item );
        }

            return collection;
    }
}
```

I assume creating a new Collection **every** time the property is accessed is just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `BindingTest` property into `public` field.. .It will automatically bind the data to the UI...

Basically xaml allows you to bind the public properties to the UI as we have limitation over the other fields like internal and private..

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }


        public ObservableCollection<GroupBox> BindingTest
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<GroupBox> collection = new ObservableCollection<GroupBox>();
                for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
                {
                    GroupBox groupBox = new GroupBox();
                    groupBox.Header = " ... Header ... ";
                    groupBox.Content = " ... Content ... ";
                    collection.Add(groupBox);
                }

                return collection;
            }
        }
    }
```

xaml code as follows

```
<Grid >
        <StackPanel x:Name="Dynamic" >
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BindingTest, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type this:MainWindow}}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=Header}"
                                  Content="{Binding Path=Content}">
                        </GroupBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```